# jquery converting to utc and iso date

Tags: jquery, date, utc, iso

I am converting a date to utc and iso in jquery but always it returns one month after after the date that i gave, here is my code

```
var x = new Date(2015,09,1).toISOString();
```

and here is the result

```
x = "2015-09-30T21:00:00.000Z"
```

for UTC also returns one month after.any help thanks

Comment: its starts from zero , 0 is January

Comment: so do i have to subtract the month by one ?

Comment: yes you should do that

Comment: thanks for your help, why don't put on answer so i can mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date starts from zero (0) ,so you should subtract 1 to get actual date...means for 0 corresponding to January in date